# How to get the style value in a div tag in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I desire to crawl images in a single webpage, and the image URLs are in a div tag, which are validated as a style value, like so:

```
<div class="v-image__image v-image__image--cover" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/f3ea4910e239eb704af755c65f548e35_car.png&quot;); background-position: center center;"></div>
```

I want to get that: `https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/f3ea4910e239eb704af755c65f548e35_car.png`

But when I try chrome driver find elements or soup.find they return empty lists and that's because the text between the div tag is nothing.

I'm looking for a way to get **inside** the div tag, not between.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: BeautifulSoup - Get an attribute value from the name of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154966/python-beautifulsoup-get-an-attribute-value-from-the-name-of-a-class)

Comment: @mx0 It's just the same problem, but it didn't print out anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the `images` you should, `use presence of all the elements.`

Once you've the **list** in `Python`, such as `all_images` (See below), you can `remove the ()` and `""` like below.

**Sample code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
links = []
driver.get("https://mashinbank.com/ad/GkbI20tzp3/%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF-111-SE-1397")
all_images = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'v-image__image--cover')]")))
for image in all_images:
    a = image.get_attribute('style')
    b = a.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].replace('"', '')
    links.append(b)

print(links)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
['https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/cabdf9f3f379e5b839300f89a90ab27e_car.png', 'https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/e1c6c75dda980a6b4b4a83932ed49832_car.png', 'https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/81ef7c57ca349485a9ba78bf0e42e13f_car.png', 'https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/02bd13f2c5ce936ec3db10706c03854d_car.png', 'https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/cabdf9f3f379e5b839300f89a90ab27e_car.png', 'https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/e1c6c75dda980a6b4b4a83932ed49832_car.png', 'https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/81ef7c57ca349485a9ba78bf0e42e13f_car.png', 'https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files/7uPtEVa0plEFoNExiYHcbtL1rQnpIGnnPHVuvKKu/02bd13f2c5ce936ec3db10706c03854d_car.png']
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium solution for this issue can be as following:
You probably should wait for the element visibility and only after that to extract the element attribute.
Split the entire style attribute to get the url value.
Like this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@style,'https://mashinbank.com/api/parse/files')]")))
style_content = element.get_attribute("style")
url = style_content.split(";")[1]
```

Comment: Thank you, 1 more thing: there are many links in the webpage depending on the count of images, this code gives me 1 link and then an error: `in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: To be more clear: [link](https://mashinbank.com/ad/GkbI20tzp3/%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF-111-SE-1397) The goal is to download all of the images in this webpage.